# Reading data from a file, only alpha characters

Tags: c

I'm working on a program for school right now in c and I'm having trouble reading text from a file.  I've only ever worked in Java before so I'm not completely familiar with c yet and this has got me thoroughly stumped even though I'm sure it's pretty simple.

Here's an example of how the text can be formatted in the file we have to read:

boo22$Book5555bOoKiNg#bOo#TeX123tEXT(JOHN)

I have to take in each word and store it in a data structure, and a word is only alpha characters, so no numbers or special characters.  I already have the data structure working properly so I just need to get each word into a char array and then add it to my structure. It has to keep reading each char until it gets to a non-alpha char value.  I've tried looking into the different ways to scan in from a file and I'm not sure what would be best for my scenario.

Here's the code I have right now for my input:

```
char str[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
char c;
int index = 0;

while (fscanf(dictionaryInputFile, "%c", c) != EOF) //while not at end of file
{   
    if (isalpha(c)) //if current character is a letter
    {
        tolower(c); //ignores case in word
        str[index] = c; //add char to string
        index++;
    }
    else if (str[0] != '\0') //If a word
    {
        str[index] = '\0'; //Make sure no left over characters in String
        dictionaryRoot = insertNode(str, dictionaryRoot); //insert word to dictionary
        index = 0; //reset index
        str[index] = '\0'; //Set first character to null since word has been added
    }
}
```

My thinking was that if it doesn't hit that first if statement then I have to check if str is a word or not, that's why it checks if the 0 index of str is null or not.  I'm guessing the else if statement I have is not right though, but I can't figure out a way to end the current word I'm building and then reset str to null when it's added to my data structure.  Right now when I run this I get a segmentation fault if I pass the txt file as an argument.

I'd just like to know if I'm on the right track and if not maybe some help on how I should be reading this data.

This is my first time posting here so I hope I included everything you'll need to help me, if not just let me know and I'd be happy to add more information.

Comment: 1) `fscanf(dictionaryInputFile, "%c", c)` --> `fscanf(dictionaryInputFile, "%c", &c)`

Comment: 2) Word being processed when the loop terminates is not added.

Comment: Suggest `int c; while ((c = fgetc(dictionaryInputFile)) != EOF)`   –(Thanks @BLUEPIXY).

Comment: BTW: Welcome and decent 1st question.

Comment: The input file has to be opened for read before trying to read from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biggest problem: Incorrect use of `fscanf()`. @BLUEPIXY

```
// while (fscanf(dictionaryInputFile, "%c", c) != EOF)
while (fscanf(dictionaryInputFile, "%c", &c) != EOF)
```

No protection against overflow.

```
// str[index] = c; //add char to string
if (index >= MAX_WORD_SIZE - 1) Handle_TooManySomehow();
```

Not sure why testing against `'\0'` when `'\0'` is also a non-alpha.

Pedantically, `isalpha()` is problematic when a signed `char` is passed.  Better to pass the `unsigned char` value: `is...((unsigned char) c))`, when code knows it is not `EOF`.  Alternatively, save the input using `int ch = fgetc(stream)` and use `is...(ch))`.

Minor: Better to use `size_t` for array indexes than `int`, but be careful as `size_t` is unsigned.  `size_t` is important should the array become *large*, unlike in this case.

Also, when `EOF` received, any data in `str` is ignored, even if it contained a word. @BLUEPIXY.

For the most part, OP is on the right track.

---

Follows is a sample non-tested approach to illustrate not overflowing the buffer.

Test for full buffer, then read in a `char` if needed.  If a non-alpha found, add to dictionary if a non-zero length work was accumulated.

```
char str[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
int ch;
size_t index = 0;

for (;;) {
  if ((index >= sizeof str - 1) ||
      ((ch = fgetc(dictionaryInputFile)) == EOF) ||
      (!isalpha(ch))) {
    if (index > 0) {
      str[index] = '\0';
      dictionaryRoot = insertNode(str, dictionaryRoot);
      index = 0;
    }
    if (ch == EOF) break;
  }
  else {
    str[index++] = tolower(ch);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Everything you said makes sense, especially in protecting against overflow because that was something I didn't know to do.  Glad to know I was mostly on the right track though.

Comment: The suggested code contains a compile error due to mismatched parens.  also, the int variable 'c' needs to be 'reduced' to a char before being put in the char array 'str[]'

Comment: @user3629249 1) Paren issue fixed. 2) suspect you are thinking C++ concerning "int variable 'c' needs to be 'reduced' to a char".  `char c = '\0';` needs no reduction.  `'\0'`, in C, is an `int`.  Why should `int ch; char c = tolower(ch);` need a reduction?